# LTspice- resistors, currents, ammeter

Tags: current, resistors, ltspice

How to add ideal ammeters and with them get currents of R6 and R7? [image]

Comment: Hi Filip, I've rolled back the edit to your question that removed the picture as it deletes context from the question. Please make sure you don't leave people asking what you mean after editing a question--without th eimage, there's no way to know what you mean by "R6 and R7", and it's not obvious that you're even talking about LTspice schematic capture (rather than, e.g., using LTspice to simulate a schematic-less netlist).

Answer (score 4):

There are no ammeters in SPICE (though you can use a zero-volt voltage source as one). If you want to know the current through a two-terminal component, simply click on the component. If you want to know the current into one pin of a multi-pin component, click on that pin of the component (the mouse cursor will turn into a current probe to show it's in the right place).

Comment: Thank you, so should I set V1 to zero then?

Comment: @Filip No, I mean you can add a voltage source and use that as an ammeter if you really want one. I have never done that, but I've seen people recommend it before.

Comment: Okay, thank you, that has really been helpful. If you understand LTspice well, could you maybe go and check my other question regarding LTspice? Would really be nice.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Hearth’s answer: To display the current in a wire between two nodes, insert a small resistance (1 micro-ohm). Clicking on the resistor will display the current.

Comment: Thank you for another useful information! If you could go and check my other question regarding LTspice, I would really be thankful

Answer (score 0):

You can place labels showing the initial DC operating voltages and currents on the schematic.

*RMB* = right mouse button click

Be sure `Show .op Data Flags` is enabled [blank area in the schematic: *RMB -> View -> Show .op Data Flags* needs to have a check-mark].

To place an .op data flag label, *RMB on a wire -> Place .op Data Label*

This label can be moved and edited. If you want to place a current label, you need to make a voltage label and edit it to display the desired current. Move the edited label to where you want it placed.

You can edit how many decimal places are displayed by using the round function as shown in the example below.

Additional maths can be added like displaying power dissipated by R2 as shown in the example below.

[image]

This information can be found at the [LTWiki site](https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice#Operating_Point_Data_Labels_.28visible_numeric_dc_bias_values.29).